# c++ - trying to insert node into vector <node> but program keep crashing at push_back

Tags: c++, co

So I inputted bunch of strings into a linkedlist. I tend try to input these nodes into vector.
But program just kept crashing whenever I try to push_back. Here is my code. I have two class, node and heap.

```
heap h;
    vector<Node> *vstring;
```

After trying Dennis solution, I was able to fixed the problem. However I am having an another problem. To test if the content is actually in the vector

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
     cout << "content is " << h[i] << endl;
}
```

I get this following error. 
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'std::vector')
    cout << *h << endl;
         ^
In node class, I do have the << operator overloaded.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Node &n)
{
    cout << "in operator " << endl;
    out<<n.data;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: 99% of the time dynamically allocating a vector object is a mistake. Just use `vector<Node> myvec`

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<Node> *vstring;
```

is not initialized.
Try

```
vector<Node> *vstring = new vector<Node>();
```

Comment: Yes this seem to fix the problem. However I have an another problem. I cant seem to output the vector content. I get an error saying I must overload << operator. I did cout << h[0] << endl;. Is there way to get around it without having to write a function to overload <<?

Comment: This means that the element in the vector (in this case of type Node) cannot be converted to a string. Now if you have a toString() (or similar) function in your node class, you could output it this way:
    cout << h[0].toString() << endl;

Comment: well... if `h` is `std::vector<Node> *` then `h[0]` is not what you think it is. Use `h->at(0)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as stated by others, you have uninitialized pointer.

Secondly, I don't see a good reason for writing:

```
std::vector<Node> *vstring;
```

instead of:

```
std::vector<Node> vstring;
```

Vector implementation will dynamically allocate its content, so you don't have to be concerned about its size. If you want to create an array of vectors, use `std::vector<std::vector<Node>> vstring` and getting and `[i, j]` element will be just like in case of arrays - `vstring[i][j]`.

When passing `h` as `std::vector<Node> *`, `h` is not a `vector` it's a pointer. So using `h[i]` you are getting i-th vector under pointer `h`. The error you saw told you this -

> operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and **'std::vector'**) cout << *h << endl;

It means that the argument of operator `<<` is a vector (in your case `cout << "content is " <<`**h[i]**`<< endl;`

If you want to get element of vector under pointer `h` you should do `h->at(i)` (or `(*h)[i]`).

Also it would be better to use references instead of pointers, like this:

```
void heap::getData(std::vector<Node> &h, int size, Node* temp);
```

So there would be no problem with `h[i]`.

Comment: I totally forgot about using &. Orginally I had it just vstring but program wouldn't compile. Thanks. And yes after using &, I was able to use h[i]. However, when I am couting it, there seem to be nothing in it. At first, I thought it might be because my temp.getdata() is not getting the string but I checked and it is getting the string and is storing in word. But for some reason, push_back is not pushing in the variable word.

Comment: So I don't exactly the reason behind it but I was able to solve the problem by using stringstream to convert the h[i] into string. It works. Any explanation?

Comment: As I see your `temp.getData()` returns a string. And you are pushing this string into vector of Nodes. Is it intended? Do you have any Node constructor which takes only string? I would have to see your Node class.

Comment: Yes it was intended. My node class only handles string. I have my node constructor construct data = ""; and all the pointers to NULL.

Comment: I would have to see the code. From what you are saying, using stringstream does not make any sense.  I don't have enough information.

Comment: I have added the code below. After I looked at my code, I noticed I am doing const string& Node::getData() const; So I just changed it to string and now its working.

Comment: Also could my operator = be having problem? I am trying to swap between two vector nodes. So first I created a vector<Node> temp; and then I did temp = h[i]; Program crashed at that part

Comment: Sorry, your code is not here. I can't help you without it.